# I have define a Function in controller and calling from component event, facing below issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

****This is my component details**** 
Attribute:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="ABC" type="string" default="false"/>
```

**This is lightning button details**

```
<lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.doSubmit}"> 
</lightning:button>
```

**THis is my funtion doSubmit in controller**

```
({
    doSubmit : function(cmp, evt, hlpr) {
 //accessing the value in attribute ABC
        var initialABCValue = cmp.get("v.abc");
             if(initialABCValue == "true"){
                      alert("Value is true");
 //setting value of ABC to false
            cmp.set("v.abc","false");
        }
            else{
                     alert("Value is False");
 //setting value of ABC to true
            cmp.set("v.abc","true");
        }
    }
})
```

Now on click on button "Submit" on Page  i should get initially false value ,on next click it should be true value accordingly .As my function says so

I am not getting changin vlaues on pop up just getting "False"
Can you helpmeguys with correction in code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightning is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. This includes component names, attribute names, JavaScript functions, expressions, etc.

As such, it should be:

```
var initialABCValue = cmp.get("v.ABC");
```

Also, it would probably make more sense to have this attribute be a Boolean instead:

```
<aura:attribute name="ABC" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

...

```
var initialABCValue = cmp.get("v.ABC");
if(initialABCValue) {
   // ...
   cmp.set("v.ABC",false);
} else {
   // ...
   cmp.set("v.ABC",true);
}
```

Or even just:

```
var initialABCValue = cmp.get("v.ABC");
cmp.set("v.ABC", !initialABCValue);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply ,I have changed it to small letetters in Component  code.It works fine .